# Carrusel with React

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I imported React-bootstrap Carousel but it is not been showed as the docuemntation... I

```
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
```

```
 <div className='carru'>
                    <Carousel>
                        <Carousel.Item>
                            <img
                            className="d-block w-100"
                            src={img1}
                            alt="First slide"
                            />
                        </Carousel.Item>
                        <Carousel.Item>
                            <img
                            className="d-block w-100"
                            src={img2}
                            alt="Second slide"
                            />
                        </Carousel.Item>
                        <Carousel.Item>
                            <img
                            className="d-block w-100"
                            src={img3}
                            alt="Third slide"
                            />
                        </Carousel.Item>
                        </Carousel.Item>
                    </Carousel>
                </div>
        </div>
```

I tried using other carousels but it happens the same...

This is how it is shown

[How my problems looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP3ab.png)

Comment: Are you sure 'react-bootstrap/Carousel' as been added correctly? Are other elements, such as buttons, being rendered correctly?

Comment: I think not... How can I be sure of that? I'm new with React so I know only the basic of it's theory

Comment: Try adding a button as mentioned here https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/

Comment: Make sure you have completed the steps in https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/ especially adding CSS to App.js file as mentioned under the CSS heading https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#css

Comment: Okay, sure, I will see if I missed something there... thanks!

Comment: I forgot to add a script in my `index.html` file...